# Passing in an argument through Eclipse CDT

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'm having trouble passing in a simple string argument through the Eclipse CDT. This is my code at the moment:

```
/*
 * ProgramOne.c
 */

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char check = getchar();
    printf("%c\n", check);
    return (0);
}
```

I go to Run -> Run Configurations -> Arguments, and put in "abcd" (with and without the quotes) and run it. However, nothing prints. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

What you are setting, is a command line argument. If you replace main's declaration with:

```
int main(int argc, char  **argv[]) {
```

You would be able to dereference the string abcd from argv[1]. This is effectively making abcd an argument to main.

In your program code, you are calling getchar from user input. That would be where you type in a character, and press enter.